# Invertibility of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $L_1$ and $L_2$ are two independent random variables which are either 0 or 1, where $P(L_1 = 0) = P(L_2 = 0) =p_1$ and $P(L_1 = 1) = P(L_2 = 1) =p_2$. Let

$R(L_1,L_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
R_{11}(L_1,L_2) & R_{12}(L_1,L_2) \\
R_{12}(L_1,L_2)^{T} & R_{22}(L_1,L_2).
\end{bmatrix}$

Assume that $R(L_1,L_2)$ is positive definite for any $L_1 =0,1$, $L_2=0,1$.
Now we define the following matrix:

<sub>\begin{align}
&Q= \\
&\begin{bmatrix}
E[R_{11}(L_1,L_2) | L_1 = 0] &0 & E[R_{12}(L_1,L_2) | L_1 = 0, L_2=0] 
&E[R_{12}(L_1,L_2) | L_1 = 0, L_2=1]
 \\
0 &E[R_{11}(L_1,L_2) | L_1 = 1] & E[R_{12}(L_1,L_2) | L_1 = 1, L_2=0] 
&E[R_{12}(L_1,L_2) | L_1 = 1, L_2=1] 
\\
E[R_{12}(L_1,L_2)^{T} | L_1 = 0, L_2=0] &E[R_{12}(L_1,L_2)^{T} | L_1 = 1, L_2=0] & E[R_{22}(L_1,L_2) | L_2=0] 
&0
 \\
E[R_{12}(L_1,L_2)^{T} | L_1 = 0, L_2=1] &E[R_{12}(L_1,L_2)^{T} | L_1 = 1, L_2=1] & 0 &E[R_{22}(L_1,L_2) | L_2=1] 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}</sub>

which can be written as

<sub>\begin{align}
&Q=\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 R_{11}(0,0) + p_2 R_{11}(0,1) &0 & R_{12}(0,0)
& R_{12}(0,1)
 \\
0 & p_1 R_{11}(1,0) + p_2 R_{11}(1,1) & R_{12}(1,0) 
& R_{12}(1,1)
\\
R_{12}(0,0)^{T} & R_{12}(1,0)^{T} & p_1 R_{22}(0,0) + p_2 R_{22}(1,0) 
&0
 \\
R_{12}(0,1)^{T} & R_{12}(1,1)^{T} & 0 & p_1 R_{22}(0,1) + p_2 R_{22}(1,1).
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}</sub>

Is $Q$ invertible? I think so, but don't know how we can show that. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to choose all matrices the same, say, $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and test the positive definiteness on some simple vector like $[1,1,1,1]$?

Comment: @fedja The matrix you mentioned is PSD, my assumption is that they are PD.

Comment: Who cares? This is a stable problem. If you really want to insist on this difference,, use $\begin{bmatrix}1&-0.9\\-0.9&1\end{bmatrix}$ instead.

Comment: @fedja if we choose all matrices $[1, -0.6; -0.6, 1]$, then $Q$ is not PD. Thanks

Comment: @fedja Actually what I needed was to know whether $Q$ is invertible. So, I tried to see whether it is PD. But, that is not necessary. Do you have any idea for showing its invertibility?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can make it non-invertible too: use $-0.5$ instead of $-0.6$ in that example or just notice that if something can be made both PD and non-PD, then, interpolating between the two cases (say, linearly), you'll hit a degenerate matrix somewhere.

Comment: @ I meant, assuming that the $R$ matrices are PD. -0.5 doesn't work

Comment: What? $\begin{bmatrix}1&-0.5\\-0.5&1\end{bmatrix}$ is PD, isn't it?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is PD. But I need the $R$ matrices to be different.

Comment: Then just perturb them a little bit.